# Flot - Create multiple series bar chart and add multiple colors to one of the series

Tags: jquery, flot

I need to create the following chart using jquery flot.
I think to create it with multiple series but I have the following problem:
I need the one series to be in different colors for each bar (the first in the image), and I found support only for one color for each series.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: Please post a bit of code used to create those bars, otherwise we won't be able to help you out

Comment: Try the [side-by-side](http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/labs/flot) or [side-by-side improved](https://github.com/pkoltermann/SideBySideImproved) plugin and come back when you have more questions. Multiple colors for one data series are not easy to implement. Try seperating the data in multiple series if you need it.